# How to access System.ComponentModel.DesignProperties?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a user control in my project that crashes at design-time when I try to add it to a form, so I want to add in a check to see if we're at design time.  From what I've read, that's done by calling the function:

```
System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)
```

from the user control.  The problem I'm having is that VS2013 is telling me that "DesignProperties" does not exist in the current context.

I've got "**using System.ComponentModel**" in there, so I dunno what's wrong.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for WPF and DesignerProperties is found only in **PresentationFramework** (in PresentationFramework.dll), where the parameter passed to the **GetIsInDesignMode** is a **System.Windows.DependencyObject**

For WinForms you can check it with

```
if (!DesignMode)
```